# Testing prediction very off while training prediction pretty good

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I've created an artificial neural network where I'm trying to predict a certain value from 8 input features. My results for my training set are okay, RMSE gets to around 7 which is fine for now, and when I plot the predictions from the testing set from training data to actual values, it looks pretty close. But, when I try and predict a second set of data the predictions are very off and the plots do not align much at all. From what I've read it seems very much like an overfitting issue, so I've tried dropout layers, lessening the amount of nodes in each later, and regularization, but I've been having trouble figuring this out. I've seen posts similar to this, but the suggestions on them haven't played much of an affect for me, so I appreciate any suggestions or edits.

The dataset I'm using, I've split up as well myself to try and predict the second half of the data from the trained first half. I mainly did this because I was having trouble plotting and visualizing the testing split data, so I'm not sure if that is a contributor.

dataset:
[https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BQOXffFYioCiPug2VcBZEZVD-u3y9bcl?usp=sharing][1]](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BQOXffFYioCiPug2VcBZEZVD-u3y9bcl?usp=sharing%5D%5B1%5D)

```
X = df.iloc[:, 1:9]
y = df.iloc[:,9]
print(X)
print(y)
df.head()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, shuffle = True)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, shuffle = True)

[verbose, epochs, batch_size] = [1, 200, 32]

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu',input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))

earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience = 20, verbose =1, mode = 'auto')

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, verbose = verbose, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks = [earlystopper])

Epoch 1/200
114/114 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 7394.9355 - root_mean_squared_error: 85.9935 - val_loss: 5504.9204 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 74.1948
Epoch 2/200
114/114 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 4345.6743 - root_mean_squared_error: 65.9213 - val_loss: 3574.7473 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 59.7887
Epoch 3/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 3233.9028 - root_mean_squared_error: 56.8669 - val_loss: 2896.8821 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 53.8221
Epoch 4/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2783.2778 - root_mean_squared_error: 52.7562 - val_loss: 2560.7373 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 50.6031
Epoch 5/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 2564.8101 - root_mean_squared_error: 50.6433 - val_loss: 2542.7334 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 50.4248
Epoch 6/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2382.3220 - root_mean_squared_error: 48.8083 - val_loss: 2239.1902 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 47.3193
Epoch 7/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2197.5144 - root_mean_squared_error: 46.8768 - val_loss: 2012.0956 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 44.8554
Epoch 8/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2008.3439 - root_mean_squared_error: 44.8136 - val_loss: 1886.7860 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 43.4361
Epoch 9/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1836.7925 - root_mean_squared_error: 42.8567 - val_loss: 1639.8645 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 40.4940
Epoch 10/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1674.8507 - root_mean_squared_error: 40.9236 - val_loss: 1509.7224 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 38.8537
Epoch 11/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1541.2583 - root_mean_squared_error: 39.2574 - val_loss: 1365.2268 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 36.9474
Epoch 12/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1421.3064 - root_mean_squared_error: 37.6986 - val_loss: 1293.4971 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 35.9635
Epoch 13/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1324.8605 - root_mean_squared_error: 36.3969 - val_loss: 1198.7233 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 34.6207
Epoch 14/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1284.6041 - root_mean_squared_error: 35.8395 - val_loss: 1337.0155 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 36.5633
Epoch 15/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1216.3502 - root_mean_squared_error: 34.8742 - val_loss: 1081.3723 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 32.8820
Epoch 16/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1162.0311 - root_mean_squared_error: 34.0864 - val_loss: 1133.2288 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 33.6613
Epoch 17/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1104.8784 - root_mean_squared_error: 33.2374 - val_loss: 993.6311 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 31.5195
Epoch 18/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1045.4672 - root_mean_squared_error: 32.3313 - val_loss: 983.1470 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 31.3526
Epoch 19/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 992.3822 - root_mean_squared_error: 31.4995 - val_loss: 889.3832 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 29.8198
Epoch 20/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 952.0421 - root_mean_squared_error: 30.8525 - val_loss: 841.9726 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 29.0139
Epoch 21/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 917.5254 - root_mean_squared_error: 30.2879 - val_loss: 792.9581 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 28.1564
Epoch 22/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 862.7592 - root_mean_squared_error: 29.3698 - val_loss: 817.9950 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 28.5975
Epoch 23/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 827.7817 - root_mean_squared_error: 28.7681 - val_loss: 737.3447 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 27.1508
Epoch 24/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 802.2929 - root_mean_squared_error: 28.3215 - val_loss: 758.1763 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 27.5316
Epoch 25/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 747.4509 - root_mean_squared_error: 27.3361 - val_loss: 661.6873 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 25.7196
Epoch 26/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 730.4260 - root_mean_squared_error: 27.0228 - val_loss: 809.2615 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 28.4441
Epoch 27/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 713.3840 - root_mean_squared_error: 26.7056 - val_loss: 619.2453 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 24.8806
Epoch 28/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 640.7632 - root_mean_squared_error: 25.3093 - val_loss: 582.9537 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 24.1402
Epoch 29/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 623.6390 - root_mean_squared_error: 24.9686 - val_loss: 576.0305 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 23.9963
Epoch 30/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 597.2028 - root_mean_squared_error: 24.4334 - val_loss: 536.8599 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 23.1657
Epoch 31/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 578.3903 - root_mean_squared_error: 24.0453 - val_loss: 523.5475 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 22.8764
Epoch 32/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 542.2120 - root_mean_squared_error: 23.2808 - val_loss: 471.9659 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 21.7197
Epoch 33/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 520.8909 - root_mean_squared_error: 22.8182 - val_loss: 453.8963 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 21.2996
Epoch 34/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 483.3801 - root_mean_squared_error: 21.9808 - val_loss: 451.4026 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 21.2409
Epoch 35/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 479.9437 - root_mean_squared_error: 21.9024 - val_loss: 439.3797 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 20.9559
Epoch 36/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 448.5528 - root_mean_squared_error: 21.1736 - val_loss: 412.7776 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 20.3112
Epoch 37/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 423.9225 - root_mean_squared_error: 20.5837 - val_loss: 418.4279 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 20.4498
Epoch 38/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 407.1509 - root_mean_squared_error: 20.1721 - val_loss: 368.4748 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 19.1895
Epoch 39/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 391.0860 - root_mean_squared_error: 19.7699 - val_loss: 371.3289 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 19.2637
Epoch 40/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 386.5649 - root_mean_squared_error: 19.6551 - val_loss: 438.2267 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 20.9281
Epoch 41/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 378.0979 - root_mean_squared_error: 19.4385 - val_loss: 334.8956 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 18.2935
Epoch 42/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 355.8591 - root_mean_squared_error: 18.8577 - val_loss: 332.4010 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 18.2251
Epoch 43/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 338.0428 - root_mean_squared_error: 18.3792 - val_loss: 331.5258 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 18.2010
Epoch 44/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 339.5553 - root_mean_squared_error: 18.4202 - val_loss: 326.8555 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 18.0722
Epoch 45/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 321.3495 - root_mean_squared_error: 17.9192 - val_loss: 305.4382 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 17.4696
Epoch 46/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 301.2448 - root_mean_squared_error: 17.3491 - val_loss: 301.4022 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 17.3536
Epoch 47/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 292.2045 - root_mean_squared_error: 17.0865 - val_loss: 299.6260 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 17.3023
Epoch 48/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 284.1794 - root_mean_squared_error: 16.8500 - val_loss: 312.1617 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 17.6608
Epoch 49/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 280.3943 - root_mean_squared_error: 16.7372 - val_loss: 267.4419 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 16.3457
Epoch 50/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 272.3135 - root_mean_squared_error: 16.4940 - val_loss: 272.8264 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 16.5095
Epoch 51/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 258.9450 - root_mean_squared_error: 16.0836 - val_loss: 324.6610 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 18.0110
Epoch 52/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 266.9457 - root_mean_squared_error: 16.3304 - val_loss: 258.2507 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 16.0619
Epoch 53/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 247.7654 - root_mean_squared_error: 15.7321 - val_loss: 265.2635 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 16.2787
Epoch 54/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 254.8157 - root_mean_squared_error: 15.9545 - val_loss: 236.3308 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 15.3643
Epoch 55/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 230.8830 - root_mean_squared_error: 15.1859 - val_loss: 240.2249 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 15.4904
Epoch 56/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 226.1049 - root_mean_squared_error: 15.0278 - val_loss: 238.8484 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 15.4459
Epoch 57/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 231.0009 - root_mean_squared_error: 15.1897 - val_loss: 230.8822 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 15.1858
Epoch 58/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 231.8551 - root_mean_squared_error: 15.2178 - val_loss: 240.2904 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 15.4924
Epoch 59/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 218.5941 - root_mean_squared_error: 14.7756 - val_loss: 280.2425 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 16.7322
Epoch 60/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 215.3654 - root_mean_squared_error: 14.6659 - val_loss: 212.6626 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 14.5735
Epoch 61/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 197.6626 - root_mean_squared_error: 14.0494 - val_loss: 192.4115 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 13.8612
Epoch 62/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 192.4198 - root_mean_squared_error: 13.8615 - val_loss: 233.2400 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 15.2631
Epoch 63/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 211.5312 - root_mean_squared_error: 14.5345 - val_loss: 198.8049 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 14.0899
Epoch 64/200
114/114 [==============================] - 1s 12ms/step - loss: 201.0884 - root_mean_squared_error: 14.1707 - val_loss: 181.3378 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 13.4558
...
Epoch 197/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 38.6365 - root_mean_squared_error: 6.1893 - val_loss: 40.4071 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 6.3308
Epoch 198/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 38.8703 - root_mean_squared_error: 6.2082 - val_loss: 43.4462 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 6.5664
Epoch 199/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 45.9887 - root_mean_squared_error: 6.7572 - val_loss: 49.0946 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 6.9832
Epoch 200/200
114/114 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 45.1933 - root_mean_squared_error: 6.6981 - val_loss: 47.3281 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 6.8556
```

Comment: post the dataset.

Comment: okay it's posted

Comment: You most likely need to use an LSTM. Your dataset uses time sequences.

Comment: I added an LSTM layer and am getting better results for the training and testing sets, but still bad results on a second dataset. What else could be the problem with that second dataset?